# Twice Up On Top

Tags: chess

Here is a chess problem I've made that has an illegal position. The board is from White’s view and White’s d1 pawn moves normally. Have fun!

**White moves and mates in 19 moves**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same basic idea as Barsloai, but refined a bit to actually achieve mate in 19. All of black's lines should be accounted for.

> [FEN "5brb/4p1p1/3pPpPp/3p3P/7p/5PpP/PP4Pp/3P1K1k w - - 0 1"]
>
>   1. b4 f5 {Black can move pawns in a different order, but it won't matter.}
>
>   2. b5 f4
>
>   3. b6 d4
>
>   4. b7 d5
>
>   5. b8=Q d3
>
>   6. Qb2 d4
>
>   7. a4 d2 {d2 cannot be the last pawn move, so d2 must have been made by this point regardless of move order.}
>
>   8. Qxd2 d3 {Last pawn move; variations have collapsed.}
>
>   9. Ke1 Kg1
>
>   10. Qxd3 h1=Q (10... Kh1 11. Qf1#)
>
>   11. Qf1+ Kh2
>
>   12. Qxh1+ Kxh1
>
>   13. Kf1 Kh2
>
>   14. a5 Kh1
>
>   15. a6 Kh2
>
>   16. a7 Kh1
>
>   17. a8=Q Kh2
>
>   18. Qa7 Kh1
>
>   19. Qg1#

Answer (score 4):

I thin this. should work. Excuse me for not knowing exactly how to describe chess move in English as normally I do it in my native tongue-hopefully you'll understand

> 1. b4, d4
>  2. b5, d3
>  3. b6, d2
>  4. b7, d5
>  5. b8=Q, d4
>  6. Qb2, d3
>  7. Q:d2, f5
>  8. Ke1, f4
>  9. Qb1, d2
>  10. Q:d2, Kg1
>  11. Qe2, h1>Q
>  12. Qf1+, Kh2
>  13. Q:h1, K:h1
>  14. Kf1, Kh2
>  15. a4, Kh1
>  16. a5, Kh2
>  17. a6, Kh1
>  18. a7, Kh2
>  19. a8>Q, Kh1
>  20. Qa7, kh2
>  21. Qg1 #

Comment: Darn, I can't seem to be able to make it into a spoiler, sorry, advices will be welcomed

Comment: I've edited your answer, so now it's a spoiler. Good work!

Comment: Thanks for editing buddy, I appreciate it